# Interpolate between two times of a date using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I need to interpolate the temperature at 15:00:00 everyday from four daily measurements of temperatures at different times.

Here is the readings of two days below which shows the data are recorded not so evenly everyday:

```
datetime    temp_obs
2011-12-11 05:29:45 16.02
2011-12-11 11:28:19 15.79
2011-12-11 17:26:52 16.15
2011-12-11 23:25:26 16.71
2011-12-12 05:24:00 16.36
2011-12-12 11:22:33 16.02
2011-12-12 17:21:07 16.24
2011-12-12 23:19:40 16.63
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to formulate interpolation of the value at 15:00:00 using Pandas or any other tool. Thanks

Comment: "ARIMA time series" is what you need... glhfdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice between two times and generate the data for your regression:

```
data = df[(df.index > start_date) & (df.index <= end_date)]

valuelist = data.values
time = data.index.total_seconds()
```

You can then use numpy to fit a line to the data

```
import numpy as np
# 1d line y= mx +c
m,c = np.polyfit(time, valuelist, 1)
```

and get your desired time in seconds

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_s = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  3:00PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p').strftime('%s')   

# y = mx +c
result = m*datetime_s + c
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I worked smoothly for me! :)